# Use GIN and unique index on same column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

A field in the table needs to be a **unique** value and also be **searchable**. 
So I need a unique index on creating a row in that table, but also a ***gin index with trgm option*** for searching.

How do I approach this problem?

Do I need to only have two different names of indexes? Will that work fine?

Comment: From the docs: [*Currently, only B-tree indexes can be declared unique.*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/indexes-unique.html).

Comment: That resolved my question.

Comment: You can have two diffent indexes on the same columns with different names. Not sure what actually happens when you query the column though. EXPLAIN could help with that. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/indexes-bitmap-scans.html

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can have two indexes on the same column.

GIN indexes are typically used for arrays, JSON and full text search, and these are data types that are not candidates for a unique constraint, so I wonder about the use case.

Also, such composite types tend to be long, and there is an upper limit of somewhat more than 2000 bytes for an index tuple.

Comment: Usecase: GIN index with trgm for searching user :username but must be unique.

Comment: I see, thanks. That makes sense, as long as the name is not too long.